# (wordpress) How can I run a function in my plugin when the plugin is activated

Tags: php, wordpress

I already used register_activation_hook but it didn't work.

```
<?php
  /*
  * Plugin Name: practice
  * Plugin URI: http://ramguiao.tk
  * Description: practice
  * Version: 1.0
  * Author: Ram Guiao
  * Author URI: http://ramguiao.tk 
  */

 register_activation_hook(_FILE_,"showMessage");

 function showMessage(){
     echo "activated";
 }
```

?>

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
register_activation_hook(_FILE_,"showMessage");
```

To:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,"showMessage");
```